# Flask Restful request parsing with appropriate messages

Tags: api, rest, flask, flask-restful

I am using Flask Restful's reqparse interface for parsing request parameters. I have field for date which is required and  for which I have to performing validation

```
parser = reqparse.RequestParser(bundle_errors=True)
parser.add_argument('date',type=date_type,required=True,help='date cannot be blank')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I have defined custom date_type type for validating that string can be parsed to date using python-dateutil package

```
def date_type(date_str):
  try:
      return parser.parse(date_str)
  except:
      raise ValueError('Not a valid date format')
```

I want to return appropriate messages, if date field is missing or date is not a valid date but using add_argument, i am only allowed to have only one help message.
Does add_argument allow to have different message in case of missing and invalid data type event.

Answer (score 1):

Hie,

I think you should try [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

It will handle the invalid or missing data .

And also [flask-restful](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.5/reqparse.html) documentation states that ReqParse will be removed in upcoming version.

Comment: I aware of that,  is it possible to do same in reqparse. Also documentaton for flask-marshmallow does not contain any request parsing examples.

Comment: you should check the example in the marshmallow docs for flask.

Answer (score 1):

So as suggested by flask-restful documentation, I have to use webargs for parsing my request, behind the scenes it uses marshmallow.
Here is a sample example, that would help anyone looking to use it

```
from webargs import fields
from webargs.flaskparser import use_args

user_args={
    'user_id':fields.Int(required=True),
    'date':fields.DateTime(required=True)),
    'start_date':fields.DateTime(required=False)
    }


class User(Resource):
    #method_decorators = [requires_auth]
    @use_args(user_args)
    def get(self,args):
    return {"hello":"world"}
```

Comment: it's not working